# SQL Count-To show 10+ as result if my count exceeds 10

Tags: sql

How to show resultant counts as 10+ if the resultant count exceeds total of 10?
For eg:If my count total is 11 the resultant must be 10+

Comment: You should ask another question and show the query and an example of the current results.

Comment: If there's a query there's no need of asking this question !!!1.I am asking is there's any query to do so-Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this but I cannot be sure because your question doesn't have much detail.

```
SELECT CASE 
               WHEN ItemCount > 10 THEN '10+'
               ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ItemCount)
       END AS FinalCount
FROM
(           
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM Table1
) t
```

Comment: Assume like I am having a column named 'number'  if count(number) exceeds 10 I should get result as 10+ when I do select count(number)

Comment: That's what the code is doing. First we get the count and then we evaluate if the value is greater than 10, if so we convert it to a varchar '10+'. Otherwise it's converted to varchar count. If you already have the column with the count, the one you called "number", you can just apply the CASE WHEN that I wrote on top.